# Boolean Not operator in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, boolean, bit-manipulation

Consider the following two conditionals involving bitwise comparisons in VBScript:

```
If     1 And 3  Then WScript.Echo "yes" Else WScript.Echo "no"
If Not(1 And 3) Then WScript.Echo "yes" Else WScript.Echo "no"
```

I think the output should be:

```
yes
no
```

But the actual output is:

```
yes
yes
```

Wait a second, [the `Not` operator  is supposed to *perform logical negation on an expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cy86sfb(v=vs.84).aspx). The logical negation of `true` is `false`, as far as I know. Must I conclude that it doesn't live up to that promise? How and why and what is going on here? What is the rationale, if any?

Comment: Look at the remarks section of the link you mentioned, read where it says _In addition, the Not operator inverts the bit values of any variable and sets the corresponding bit in result according to the following table..._ In summary, for boolean operands you will get a boolean result, for numeric expression you will get numeric result.

Comment: @SalmanA, put it as an answer so I can accept it. My error started not with `Not` but with `And`, which yields a numeric result while I thought it would be boolean because of the surrounding `Not`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [VBScript AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zy95hw(v=vs.84)) performs a *logical* AND operation if both operands are boolean (True, False) -- somewhat like the C (style) language [`&&`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#logbit) operator.

If both operands are numeric, it will instead perform a *bitwise* AND operation -- somewhat like the C language [`&`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#logbit) operator.

If the operands are of mixed types then the boolean value is cast to a number -- False = 0, True = -1 (surprise!) followed by a bitwise AND operation.

So your example evaluates as follows:

```
'   1 And 3
' = &h0001 And &h0003 <- bitwise AND
' = 1
If 1 Then WScript.Echo "yes" Else WScript.Echo "no" ' Yes

'   Not(1 And 3)
' = Not(1) <- see above
' = Not(&h0001) <- bitwise NOT
' = &hFFFE
If -2 Then WScript.Echo "yes" Else WScript.Echo "no" ' Yes
```

In case you are wondering how the [VBScript NOT operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cy86sfb(v=vs.84)) works, it performs logical negation on a boolean operand like the C language [`!`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#logneg) operator and bitwise complement on a numeric operand like the C language [`~`](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/opers.html#complement) operator.

In case you want to force logical operations on operands, use the [VBScript CBool function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k9sfx3c(v=vs.84)) to cast the operands:

```
If Not(CBool(1) And CBool(3)) Then WScript.Echo "yes" Else WScript.Echo "no" ' no
```

Note: As with most VBScript operators, a `Null` operand causes the operator to return `Null`. `Null` behaves in an unusual way when used inside an `If` construct.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer to my question on [Eric Lippert's blog: **Not Logical Is VBScript**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/07/15/184431.aspx). Turns out the `Not` operator, like its brethren, is not actually a **boolean operator**.

[`And`, `Or`, `Not` and `Xor` are filed under **Logical Operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ah2h0k3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) on MSDN.

But Eric Lippert labels them as **bitwise**, and that's a better description than just **logical** as on MSDN, because **logical** doesn't say how they're actually working, so people like me get fooled into believing they're **boolean** operators, which they're not. And this is a major trap.

I would have to rewrite my statements as follows in order to have them do what I want:

```
If     (1 And 3) > 0  Then WScript.Echo "yes" Else WScript.Echo "no"
If Not((1 And 3) > 0) Then WScript.Echo "yes" Else WScript.Echo "no"
```

This prints `yes` and then `no` as it should.

**Update:** While the above does seem to work for this case, it's definitely not the way to go. The problem is in understanding what it is that I want to check for. The above code doesn't make it clear. A bitwise comparison and a numeric comparison for greater than 0 on the result are not equivalent to a boolean check.

Consider the following code, which adopts Salman A's `CBool` suggestion as the final solution to this problem:

```
Option Explicit
Dim a, b
a = -3 : b = -2

If  a And b       Then WScript.Echo "ja" Else WScript.Echo "nein" ' bad
If (a And b) > 0  Then WScript.Echo "ja" Else WScript.Echo "nein" ' bad
If CBool(a And b) Then WScript.Echo "ja" Else WScript.Echo "nein" ' good
```